# Better IDE not build using Java in Linux?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ide

First of all I love Eclipse but I'm not satisfied with its performance in Linux (Ubuntu) - It is CPU intensive and not responsive enough.

My question is if there is an IDE with most of Eclipse's functions but not built in Java. (More than a Notepad, but not a command line tool like vi or emacs).

Update: I'm looking for an IDE that I could use for Java, PHP, and Python development.

Comment: Are looking for an IDE for Java? Please state this clearly in your question.

Comment: java in linux is the a bad idea? What does that mean? of course, IDEA is an IDE you might want to try, but it is also written in Java.

Comment: Is this a serious question? I'm using Java on Ubuntu and I've nothing wrong to say about it, Java is certainly not slower or more CPU intensive on a GNU/Linux than on another platform. Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, Tomcat, GlassFish, WebLogic, etc, etc just run fine.

Comment: java in linux is slow and cpu intensive, i have a pretty good cpu but when i run java based apps like eclipse or vuze(just and example) in ubuntu its just is not the same as running them in windows or mac

Comment: btw im running ubuntu in 64bit dont know if this is the main cause why java is slow

Comment: If you are using GCJ? If you do, just switch to Sun's Java to solve your problems. But really, claiming that Java is slower on Linux than windows or mac is just a joke.

Comment: Do you have the Sun JDK installed?  Or are you using GCJ or whatever is installed by default? Try `which java` or `java -version` to see which is being used.  If you just have GCJ, install the Sun JDK.

Answer (score 2):

There's [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/), a QT4 based IDE that works on all platforms for C++ development. [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is a .NET IDE for Linux & other platforms. [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/), a commercial option, is available for Linux and works well. It's not built with Java, so you will save several MB of RAM allocation. :) It's fast. [wxStudio](http://wxStudio.sourceforge.net/) is an interesting option, if you choose to use the wxWindows libraries. There's also [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) for C++ work. Sun even provides [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), which has plugs-ins like Eclipse for other languages, yet runs a tad faster than Eclipse.

It really depends on the language you're developing in. Honestly, the majority of IDE features you're likely seeking are already natively available in Vim & Emacs... code completion, jumping to definition, breakpoints, etc. are Vim specialties. If you really want a GUI, then the languages you're using are a really important factor.

Comment: I can't say that I find MonoDevelop smoother or lighter than Eclipse :)

Comment: Code::Blocks is an outstanding IDE, and integrates well with GTest and GMock. But, the suggestion of Vim or Emacs isn't quite as helpful to inexperienced developers who might land on this page from a Google search.

Comment: I mentioned Vim because many developers have never really fully customized it and used it like an IDE. Also, there's a reason they're the only suggestions I didn't hyperlink. ;)